# div will not move up with margin or padding

Tags: html, css

I have a menu div inside another div, and I want to move it slightly up so it's level with the rest of its section, but it will not move. I've tried padding-bottom and margin-bottom. I'm not sure what is wrong.

I am very new to HTML and CSS so please bare with me if its something very obvious I'm not seeing...

Here is the code. If you preview it, you'll notice that the menu is slightly lower than it should be.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks a lot.

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url(img/roshi2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Bitstream Charter";
  font-size: small;
}

#title {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.section {
  padding: 30px 30px 0px 60px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}

.section h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px black;
}

.section p {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 1500px;
}

#menu {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 12px 150px 200px 0px;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}

a:visited {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="title">Shunryu Suzuki Roshi</div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="section">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        ut
      </p>

    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="about.html">About</a><br>
      <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a><br>
      <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a><br>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="section">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        ut
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Show a screenshot of the result you want, pls

Answer (score 0):

You want your menu to be aligned with your first section? I would just add a flexbox. See below:

```
.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  display:flex;
}
```

Or if you just want to move your menu up. You can use negative margin for your menu. See below:

```css
html, body {
  background-image: url(img/roshi2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
font-family: "Bitstream Charter";
font-size: small;
}

#title
{ font-size: 4em;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 100px;

}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.section {
  padding: 30px 30px 0px 60px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);

}

.section h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px black;
}

.section p {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 1500px;
}
#menu
{
  text-align: right;
  padding: 12px 150px 200px 0px;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  margin-top:-40px
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);

}

a:visited {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Shunryu Suzuki Roshi</title>

  </head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <body>
<header>
  <div id="title">Shunryu Suzuki Roshi</div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="section">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
                 adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
              adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          </p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="about.html">About</a><br>
      <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a><br>
      <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a><br>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="section">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
       adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html blocks are automatically aligned vertically so you need to style the html blocks to make them align horizontally , i used a css attribute called flex , you can learn about it through this website : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ check it out it's very helpful , compare my code to yours to understand more

```css
html, body {
    background-image: url(img/roshi2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Bitstream Charter";
  font-size: small;
  }
  
  #title
  { font-size: 4em;
    color: white;
    padding: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
  
  }
  
  .content {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  
  .section {
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 60px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  }
  .section-content {
    display: flex;
  }

  .section h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px black;
  }
  
  .section p {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 1500px;
  }
  #menu
  {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 12px 150px 200px 0px;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  }
  
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  a:link {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  
  }
  
  a:visited {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
```

```html
    <header>
        <div id="title">Shunryu Suzuki Roshi</div>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
      
          <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <div class="section-content">

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
               adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        </p>
        
            <div id="menu">
              <a href="about.html">About</a><br>
              <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a><br>
              <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a><br>
            </div>
            </div>
      
          </div>
      
        </div>
      
        <div class="content">
          <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
             adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
      </p>
      
          </div>
      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `.content` use the flexbox layout mode, then remove the `width` from your `p` element

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
}
.section p {
    font-size: 2em;
    /*width: 1500px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to put the menu div in another div that controls its position
Like this:

```
<div id = "menu-area">
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="about.html">About</a><br>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a><br>
            <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a><br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And then you can control the div's position easier:

```
#menu-area{
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#menu
{
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.
The problem is that you are not using `display`
There are already a few answers here about how you can use the display property
`flex` is probably the best value for your case

Comment: thanks for the tip about putting menu div into another div. I will remember that from now on. 

I think I'll have to read up on what display actually does and I will try to implement it. Thanks .